# How do I capture a value using Select-String and regex matching in PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to access the capture from a regex match using `Select-String`. Here's an example of the text.

```
'dataarea' - closed, 10,933 rows are stored
```

I would like to capture the number of rows (`10,933`).

```
PS> Select-String -Path $foo -Pattern 'closed,\s\d+[.,\d.*]{1,}' `
    | %{ $_.Matches } `
    | %{ $_.Value } > $output
```

I tried different regexes, but can't figure out how to capture just the number. This also captures the opening pattern, `closed`.

Comment: What your issue? the regex or what?

Comment: i want to be able to capture the 10,933 but can't

Comment: With regex, you typically have to look for patterns in the data so you know how to include the lines you want and exclude the lines you don't want.  You can't establish a pattern with one data point.

Comment: yes but can't i match -closed, ([0-9]+)

Comment: Maybe, but if you're the only one who knows what the rest of the data looks like, then you're the only one who knows the answer to that. You're making everyone else have to play a guessing game to try and come up with a solution for you.

Comment: Hi please see above description edit

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
'(?<=closed.*)[0-9,]+'
```

so far, there's no guaranteed that comma will always be there, or there will always be only one.

Answer (score -1):

This works with or without coma to separate 1000's:

```
$regex = '\d+[,|]+\d+'
```

Comment: Mine capture `\d+,\d+` only if before there's a  `closed`. This is what I understood was the request of the OP, but... who know ;)